# How can I check if a React or Node app is OWASP proof?

Tags: reactjs, owasp

I know what OWASP is by now but I find it too vague how perform the task of checking if an app (made of React and Node) is OWASP proof. I read about [the top 10 security risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Top_10) and I would like to know if there is any step-by-step guide or some software that would help me catching any weaknesses. Any reference to a developer story where this check is done would be appreciated.

Comment: try helmetJS library

Comment: @ivp Thanks! I think there is no easy way after all.

Comment: You can check out the cheatsheet to see how it applies to JS and others:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's tools like [vulnerability scanners](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Vulnerability_Scanning_Tools) or [package security scanners](https://snyk.io/) etc which will do some sort of automation on this. But in general, there isn't and there can't be any program which can tell you whether a given program has any or all of the top 10 security risks. Or, any general property you might want.

So automatic tools are a good idea, and there's a bunch of hosted and easy to use ones. But being aware of the code and what it does, as an engineer, is the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

The OWASP top 10 does not aim to be a standard, please read the [Introduction](https://github.com/OWASP/Top10/blob/master/2017/OWASP%20Top%2010-2017%20(en).pdf) of the document carefully. Building a good, secure software is hard - the top 10 is a good start, but you should always remember that it's only a start. Building a good, secure development lifecycle is what you're aiming for, and for that projects like [OWASP SAMM](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_SAMM_Project) or [OWASP ASVS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project) could help with. If you have a security team at your work - reach out to them and ask for help. If you don't have - me and so many other at the AppSec community would love to help you started.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.